# Summation series using matlab

Tags: matlab, series, symbolic-math

When i write this in matlab

```
syms x;
f=x^3-cos(x);
g=diff(f)
```

it gives out put as

> g =
>
> 3*x^2+sin(x)

Now I want to generate summation series as 
[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/e/1/c/e1c5e8954e1e68099d77ac15ffa765a7.png]

I google and found "symsum" command but it doesn't do my required task, when i write the following commands

```
syms k
symsum(k^2, 0, 10)
symsum(1/k^2,1,Inf)
```

it gives the out put as

> ans = 385
>
> ans = pi^2/6

Can you guys guide me how can I genereate the series which produce output as
[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/e/1/c/e1c5e8954e1e68099d77ac15ffa765a7.png]

so that when I give command diff(Sk); it should produce result as or something like that
[image]

For example in Mathematica I can do it as

[image: SummationSeries with subscript]

Your assistance will be surely of great help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have looked the help of the symsum function and you have a really good example, try this:

```
syms x;
syms k real;
symsum(x^k/sym('k!'), k, 0, inf)
```

This commands evaluate the series [image], and actually evaluates to [image]. As you can see you have to specify the term of the series with its dependence of 'k'. Then in the symsum command you have to specify that you want to sum over 'k' from 0 to inf.

So for example, you could do the following:

```
syms x;
syms k real;
ak = (-1)^k*x^(2*k+1)/sym('(2*k+1)!');
sum_ak = symsum(ak, k, 0, inf);     % gives back sin(x)
dak = diff(ak,x);
sum_dak = symsum(dak, k, 0, inf);   % should give back cos(x), but does not
A5 = symsum(ak, k, 0, 5);           % add only the first values of the series
DA5 = symsum(dak, k, 0, 5);         % add the derivated terms of the series
```

You can declare multiple symbolic variables uk and add them up:

```
syms x;
syms k real;
n = 5;
for i = 0:n
    eval(['syms u',num2str(i),' real;']);
end

A = cell(1,n);
for i=1:n
    A{i} = u0;
    for j=1:i
        eval(['A{i} = A{i} + u',num2str(j),';']);
    end
end
A{3} % check the value of A{i}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for your effort but sir I want to do with subscripts as I mentioned I want to generate series of a0+a1+a2.... and I also added the example of Mathematica. Can you help me in that regard ?

Comment: I have edited part of the code. You can make finite sums also if that's what you needed. I think that Matlab's symbolic core uses Maple's implementation or something like that. If you can do something in Maple, then you should be able to do that in symbolic Matlab. Unfortunately, I do not know much of Maple or Mathematica.