# summation series using octave

Tags: matlab, octave

Is it possible to do a summation series in Octave?

In [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875692/summation-series-using-matlab) there is `symsum` function for it, however I didn't found anything similar for octave.

For example, I want to find the following sum

[image: Summation]

---

Addendum:

Whether it's possible to sum something like this

```
f = @(x) nchoosek(5,x)*0.1.^x*0.9.^(5-x)

sum(f([0:5]))
```

Failed with error

```
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.4/m/help/print_usage.m at line 87, column 5
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.4/m/specfun/nchoosek.m at line 95, column 5
error:    at line -1, column -1
error: evaluating argument list element number 1
```

Comment: Do you want analytical solution for symbolic series summation or you just need a numerical one? `symsum` provides analytical solution and used for sumbolic series summation.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny, I need just the numeric one

Comment: Then `sum` will probably do. Provide an example of your problem and I'll give you a solution.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you don't need an analitical solution, then you don't need `symsum`. For example if you want to calculate

[image: \sum_{k=1}^{5} k]

the you can simply use `sum`

```
sum([1:5])
```

Here is another example:

[image: \sum_{k=1}^{5} \exp(-k)]

```
f = @(x) exp(-x)
sum(f([1:5]))
```

And another one with [`factorial` function](http://www.obihiro.ac.jp/~suzukim/masuda/octave/html3/octave_99.html#doc_002dfactorial):

[image: \sum_{n=0}^{5} \frac{1}{n!} \approx e]

```
g = @(n) 1 ./ factorial(n)
sum(g([0:5]))
```

the same, but without anonymous function:

```
sum(1 ./ factorial([0:5]))
```

## Update

As for your last example, `nchoosek` allows only scalar arguments. So, you'll need additional `arrayfun` call:

```
f = @(x) nchoosek(5,x)*0.1.^x*0.9.^(5-x)
sum(arrayfun(f,[0:5]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, for your answer. Could you please take a look at the addendum. I am trying to compute so far with no success.